# Mid-1990s novel where astronauts visit a moon base and discover the ghosts of the previous crew

Tags: story-identification, novel, ghost, moon

I don't remember much about this American novel published in the mid-1990s - I didn't finish it - but now I have a hankering to. It involves astronauts visiting a moonbase that has been abandoned for a long period and discovering what appears to be the ghosts of the previous crew, leading them to believe they have discovered scientific proof of life after death.